# Getting the User's Document ID to pass it to the next Page

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to ask that is it possible for a `listTile` to pass the User's Document ID to next page using the `Navigator.push` function.

Currently i'm using a `StreamBuilder` to retrieve all the data from firestore:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Registration Approval'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream:
        Firestore.instance.collection('user')
        .where('userapproval', isEqualTo: '0')
            .orderBy('FullName')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: buildUser,
      ),
    );
  }
```

And i'm using `ListView.builder` to build the `ListTile` :

```
Widget buildUser(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data.documents[index];

        return ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
              user.data['image']
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(user.data['FullName']),
          subtitle: Text(user.data['SSID']),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute
              (builder: (context) => FullDetailPage(

            )));
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The problem is that how can i pass in the user's document ID to another page. Do i store the ID into a string? So something like `String _id = user.data[ID]`.
Some example is much appreciated. Thank you.

**Not the SSID that i am referring to. The User's Document ID is the ID that is in the Firebase Firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to make it work.

i can just add in a `snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID`to retrieve the document ID.

```
onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute
              (builder: (_) => FullDetailPage(
                (snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID)
            )));
          },
```

Then by adding this 2 line of code in the `FullDetailPage`

```
final String docID;

FullDetailPage(this.docID);
```

this 2 will be able to get the doc ID. Thank you so much for those that help me out in this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the document ID by calling the [id](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/id.html) property of the `DocumentSnapshot`.

```
  DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data.documents[index];
  String documentId = user.id;
```

You can pass it through the constructor to the next page like this:

```
 Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute
   (builder: (context) => FullDetailPage(
     documentId: documentId 
 )));
```

Comment: thanks for helping man. You gave me an idea of how it works as well. Thank you so much for lending a hand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define a constructer in your `FullDetailPage` class

```
class FullDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FullDetailPage({this.documentId});

  final String documentId;

  @override
  _FullDetailPageState createState() => _FullDetailPageState();
}

class _FullDetailPageState extends State<FullDetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(widget.documentId), /// this is how you can use document id
    );
  }
}
```

And navigate to this page like this

```
Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => FullDetailPage(
                  documentId: user.data['SSID'], /// your document id
                ),
              ),
            );
```

Comment: thankyou so much for helping. You gave me the idea how it works and go around it with other approach. Thanks